# ReactJS display data from Wordpress API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React so I am just trying to pull data from my wordpress website API. I am getting a generic blog post which will display `this.state.post.link` fine but not any of the rendered data.

```
import React from 'react'

export default React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      post: {},
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    var _this = this;
    $.get('http://somewebsite.net/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1258', function(result) {
      _this.setState({
        post: result
      });
    });
  },

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.post);
    return <div className="single-post">
      <h1>{this.state.post.link}</h1>
      <h1>{this.state.post.title.rendered}</h1>
    </div>
  }
});
```

I get this error from adding  `post.title.rendered`.

```
bundle.js:51835 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined
```

This is what shows with the code `console.log(this.state.post.title);`

```
Object {rendered: "Example post"}
```

So why can I console.log this.state.post.title and it shows the object with rendered in but then if I try and display that it will say title is undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the initial state for `title.rendered` as a empty string.

```
this.state = {
  post: {
    title: {
      rendered: ''
    }
  }
...
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.post.title.rendered}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**OR**

Check if the state is defined before rendering:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.post ? this.state.post.title.rendered : null }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Reason** is you are fetching the data from api, until you didn't get the data, `this.state.post.title` will be `undefined`, and you are trying to access `rendered` of `undefined`, that's why it is throwing the error:

> Cannot read property 'rendered' of undefined

`ajax` call is `asynchronous` call, it will take time to fetch the data and `render` method will get called before that.

One solution is, put the check on `this.state.post.title`:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.post);
    return <div className="single-post">
      <h1>{this.state.post.link}</h1>
      <h1>{this.state.post.title && this.state.post.title.rendered}</h1>
    </div>
  }
```

Or hold the complete rendering until you didn't get the data, by putting the check on `this.state.post` inside `render` method.

**Update**-

Define the initial value of post as `null`:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      post: null,
    }
  },
```

Then check the value of post inside `render` method, it will not rendering anything until you didn't get the response:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.post);

    if(!this.state.post) return null;

    return <div className="single-post">
      <h1>{this.state.post.link}</h1>
      <h1>{this.state.post.title.rendered}</h1>
    </div>
}
```

**Note**: There is one issue with this, `rendered` key must be present inside `title` in response otherwise it will also throw the same error.

Comment: Ok cool, so how do I defer the render method until the data is loaded? That seems like the best solution to me

Comment: @Callum check the updated answer for that, `return null` until you didn't get the data, it will work :)

Comment: Hi thankyou, setting the initial value for post to null worked for me. So if it returns null the first time in the render method, does that mean it gets called twice?

Comment: yes, as many times you use `setState` it will triggered the `render` method, and do the change in DOM, that's how reactjs works, check the doc : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Ok thankyou and can a 404 be set in the `componentDidMount` method somehow if a 404 is returned form the ajax call?

Comment: i think, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will be helpful:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.post);
    var link = (this.state.post && this.state.post.link) ? this.state.post.link : '';
    var rendered = (this.state.post && this.state.post.title && this.state.post.title.rendered) ? this.state.post.title.rendered : '';

    return <div className="single-post">
      <h1>{link}</h1>
      <h1>{rendered}</h1>
    </div>
  }
```